# Не отображается ACF на странице

Tags: wordpress, acf

Использую тему Twenty Twenty Two, создал CPT, создал для него ACF, но на странице single не выводиться даже the_title();

код создания CPT:

```
function _post_type() {
 
    
 
    register_post_type( 'speakers', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Speakers',
            'singular_name' => 'Speakers',
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'speakers' ), 
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title','thumbnail' ), 
        'hierarchical'        => false,
            )
    ); 
}
```

Код страницы single.php а также index.php:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 *
 *
 * 
 */

get_header();

the_title();;
?>
```

Comment: Ну так код в студию) Про написать "darth", тут не совсем понял.

Comment: @Simon код чего именно? просто "darth" и я оставлю свою почту)

Comment: @Simon обновил вопрос

Comment: 1. Дебаг включен? 2. Пермалинки после регистрации пост тайпа пересохранили? 3. Лишняя `;` после `the_title();`.

Comment: @Simon извиняюсь за долгий ответ, да, это все есть, скобки убрал,не работает

Comment: @Simon, важное дополнение, после того как убрал скобки, оно отобразило тайтл, но асф так и не работает

Comment: Так Вы тут никакого ACF пока что и не показали)

Comment: @Simon разобрался, натупил немного, проблема была в иерархии файлов, спасибо, что уделили время)

Answer (score 0):

Тема 2022 - блочная. Она не использует шаблоны php.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но она вполне спокойно работает с шаблонами php и иерархией WordPress)

Comment: Вы не поняли ответ. В теме 2022 нет файлов типа header.php, footer.php, single.php и т.п. Откройте папку темы и сравните с 2021. Вот об этих шаблонах я говорил. И если вы создадите single.php в папке 2022, то он будет радостно проигнорирован.